# Split virtual machine name in Azure Powershell into pieces

Tags: azure, powershell, split, tags, virtual-machine

When new vm is created in Azure, I want to split its vmname into chunks, so I can assign them into variables. Later, I want to use them to assign tags into vm. Naming convention looks like this:

11111233444

What I want to achieve is to divide vmname and assign as variables like this:

```
$vmnane = 11111233444
split-string $wmname -some kind of string division definition command
$2 = 2
$3 = 33
$4 = 444
$r = Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceName $vmname -ResourceGroupName examplegroup
Set-AzureRmResource -Tag @{ firsttag="$2"; secondtag="$3" etc...} -ResourceId $r.ResourceId -Force
```

How I should aproach this? I had hard time finding a solution on the web.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
$vmname = 11111233444

$vmname -match '^(.{5})(.{1})(.{2})(.{3})'

$a = $Matches[1]
$b = $Matches[2]
$c = $Matches[3]
$d = $Matches[4]
```

The regEx matches the first five, the next one, the following two and the last three chars of the vm name and assigns them to the variables $a, $b, $c, $d (you should not start a variable name with a number).

Comment: Thank You very much, you're a life saver! Haven't though it can be that easy.